# How to get literal forward slashes in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

In text, can I make org-mode ignore forward slashes somehow? Phonetics uses `/s/` to denote a certain level of analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
#+OPTIONS: *:nil
```

to turn off text-emphasis (bold,italics,underline).  This will however only work on export itself, the emphasis will still be visible.

See [the manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html#fnd-126) for other export options.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you do not want the text to appear emphasized in the buffer, nor in the output. This is a slightly more complex answer which will achieve that result:

There is a variable defined by Org-mode called `org-emphasis-alist` which defines the different emphasis modes, what their plain-text syntaxes are, and how they are exported to HTML. You can achieve the result you want by changing the value of this variable *before Org-mode has been loaded*. That last part is critical so note it well—Org-mode reads the value of `org-emphasis-alist` when it is loaded and uses that value to generate a regular expression for highlighting ("font-lock") purposes.

Here are two routes to that:

1. Add the following lines to your .emacs file above the lines that load Org-mode:

   ```
   (setq org-emphasis-alist
     `(("*" bold "<b>" "</b>")
       ;; ("/" italic "<i>" "</i>")
       ("_" underline "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline;\">" "</span>")
       ("=" org-code "<code>" "</code>" verbatim)
       ("~" org-verbatim "<code>" "</code>" verbatim)
       ("+" ,(if (featurep 'xemacs) 'org-table '(:strike-through t))
        "<del>" "</del>")))
   ```

   (Notice the commented out line.)
2. Make the change through Emacs' customization facility:

   1. `M-x customize RET`
   2. In the search box enter `Org Emphasis` and click `Search`.
   3. Click the down arrow next to `Org Emphasis Alist` to reveal its value.
   4. Find and click the second `DEL` button—corresponding to the `italic` list item.
   5. Click the `Save for future sessions` button at the top of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the standard emphasis functionality of the forward slashes in org-mode, you could also just define a new environment. I put something like the following in the preamble whenever I do phonetics/phonology typesetting:

```
\newcommand\uRep[1]{$/$\textipa{#1}$/$}
```